# Aligh the child gridview columns same as that of parent gridview column's width

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I have 11 columns in parent and the same number of columns in the child as well, when I set a fixed width for the parent using HeaderStyle-Width="9%" and ItemStyle-Width="9%" it is getting reflected, but the same is not working with the Child gridview, How can I make  the column size of child gridview same as that of the parent.

```
  <div class="col-md-12 avrow" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 5px">
        <asp:GridView ID="grdNWSchParent" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="datatable" DataKeyNames="activity_group" Width="99%" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grdNWSchParent_RowDataBound">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                No Network Schedule Records Found.
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderStyle-Width="9%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <button style="background-color: transparent; color: transparent; min-width: 0px"
                            onclick="return ToggleGridPanelLevel1(this, 'tr<%#Eval("activity_group") %>')">
                            <img id="imgdiv_tr<%# Eval("activity_group") %>" border="0" src="../images/plus.jpg" alt="" />
                        </button>
                        <asp:Label ID="text" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("text") %>' CssClass="grid-item-style"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="event" HeaderText="Event" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sched_start_dt" HeaderText="Sched S" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sched_finish_dt" HeaderText="Sched F" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="baseline_Start_dt" HeaderText="BaseLine S" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="baseline_finish_dt" HeaderText="BaseLine F" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="actual_start_dt" HeaderText="Actual S" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="actual_finish_dt" HeaderText="Actual F" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="confirmed_dt" HeaderText="Confirmed" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("lgnm") %>
                        <%# Level1Row(Eval("activity_group")) %>
                        <div style="padding: 0px; width: 99%;">
                            <asp:GridView ID="grdNwSchChild1" runat="server" ShowHeader="false" DataKeyNames="activity_group" Width="99%" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grdNwSchChild1_RowDataBound">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="9%">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <table style="border: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left; 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; background-color: whitesmoke !important;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left; 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; background-color: whitesmoke !important;">
                                                        <div id="divLevel2Toggle" runat="server">
                                                            <button style="background-color: transparent; color: transparent; min-width: 0px"
                                                                onclick="return ToggleGridPanelLevel2(this, 'tr<%#Eval("activity_id") %>');" />
                                                            <img id="imgdiv_tr<%# Eval("activity_id") %>" border="0" src="../images/plus.jpg" alt="" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="border: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left; 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; background-color: whitesmoke !important;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblLevel2Text2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("text") %>' CssClass="grid-item-style"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblactivityid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("activity_id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="event" HeaderText="Event" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="sched_start_dt" HeaderText="Sched S" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="sched_finish_dt" HeaderText="Sched F" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="baseline_Start_dt" HeaderText="BaseLine S" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="baseline_finish_dt" HeaderText="BaseLine F" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actual_start_dt" HeaderText="Actual S" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actual_finish_dt" HeaderText="Actual F" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="confirmed_dt" HeaderText="Confirmed" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="lgnm" HeaderText="User" Visible="false" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#Eval("lgnm") %>
                                            <%# Level2Row(Eval("activity_id")) %>
                                            <div style="padding-left: 0px">
                                                <asp:GridView ID="grdNwSchChild2" runat="server" ShowHeader="false" Width="100%" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grdNwSchChild2_RowDataBound">
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="text" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("text") %>' CssClass="grid-item-style"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="event" HeaderText="Event" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="sched_start_dt" HeaderText="Sched S" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="sched_finish_dt" HeaderText="Sched F" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="baseline_Start_dt" HeaderText="BaseLine S" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="baseline_finish_dt" HeaderText="BaseLine F" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="actual_start_dt" HeaderText="Actual S" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="actual_finish_dt" HeaderText="Actual F" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="confirmed_dt" HeaderText="Confirmed" ItemStyle-Width="9%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblLgnm" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lgnm") %>' Visible="false" CssClass="grid-item-style"></asp:Label>
                                                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcUserDetails" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    </Columns>
                                                </asp:GridView>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Width="99%" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="99%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sharing your code would be useful

Comment: @DenseCrab : Shared